# How come this character in Bly Manor can touch objects and interact with others?

Tags: the-haunting-of-bly-manor

In the recently released Netflix series Haunting Of Bly Manor, Hannah is introduced as the housekeeper of the namesake manor.
However, it's later revealed that Hannah was dead all along, even before Dani arrives at the Manor

It was established in the series that the house ghosts cannot touch humans (which makes sense) maybe except Viola but that can be explained because she was the first ghost in the house and she's the force that keeps the other ghosts from leaving the garden of Bly Manor, and that indirectly suggests that they cannot interact with objects either. For example, when Rebecca first sees the ghost of Peter Quint, she's unable to make any physical contact with him

But if you carefully look at the scenes where Hannah was hanging out with the others in the kitchen, she was seen holding objects from her hands (for example a teacup), though she never seems to drink from them. There's this scene where she is holding a wine bottle in front of the bonfire alongside Owen, Dani and Jamie. And there are scenes where she physically interacts with other characters.

So how come Hannah touch and interact with the objects?

Comment: I've edited the title to reduce its spoileriness.

Comment: @Flater Ok. But did you edit the body of the question too? Because the Spoiler Tags I've added are gone now.

Comment: I didn't. You can check the edit history to see who did. But questions don't need to be spoiler tagged - someone who opened the question clearly wanted to read the question. Titles are the only "external" information that a site user could involuntarily stumble on and read.

Comment: @Flater Thanks for the clarification. However, one can always stumble upon a question. Is there a way to add a Spoiler Tag in the Title of the question?

Comment: A spoiler block could have been used, especially since it was just casually mentioned the entire series spoiler within the first line, not having anything to do with the question at this point. I most certainly did not expect the entire show to be spoiled so quickly when reading the question. Using the >> for blocking text iirc

Answer (score 2):

### Her denial allows her to interact with the real world.

In an [interview with Thrillist](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/the-haunting-of-bly-manor-ghosts-explained), show creator Mike Flanagan explains that because Hannah hasn't accepted her death, she can continue to interact with the real world.

> **"If you die on the grounds of Bly Manor, the first thing that happens is you go through a period of intense denial,**" Flanagan explained. It's what happens to Hannah Grose (T'Nia Miller) throughout the entirety of the series. She's simply dead this entire time, pushed by a possessed Miles into the property's well before Dani Clayton (Victoria Pedretti) arrives to look after the kids. There's a Wile E. Coyote metaphor that's used by the boy which illustrates the concept of self-awareness (something the ghosts tend to be lacking here) that's both cartoonish and downright violent.
>
> **"The idea was that this first stage of it was this dreamed life that people could still carry on,"** Flanagan continued. **"They could dream up new clothes for themselves, which Hannah does, which is why she keeps changing her outfits and seems to physically interact with the world and appears to people. They're putting up this effort because of muscle memory and denial, basically.** But once you accept the fact that you're dead, like Wile E. Coyote running off the cliff, a whole bunch of the rules immediately change."

Comment: Thanks, this works well with Hannah's perspective, she can do that till she accepts her death. But it does not answer the question how she can affect entities in real life; objects and people.